# Asterisk - Reseting CDR to show correct billsec of a new call when channel is answered beforehand

Tags: asterisk

**What I want to do:**
Answer an incoming call and Dial another number. When call is finished I need to have the correct conversation time of the call (which is supposed to be stored in ${CDR(billsec)}).
**What I am getting:**
Since the channel is answered, the C option in Dial application is only resetting the answer variable of CDR to current time therefore the resulting *billsec* is equal to duration variable of CDR and is equal to channel seize time not call conversation time.
**My dial plan:**

```
exten => 333333,1,NoOp(Here I answer the channel and make another call)
    same => n,Answer
    same => n,Dial(DAHDI/g0/123456789,,gC)
    same => n,NoOP(Billsec: ${CDR(billsec)}) // Here billsec is equal to CDR(duration)
```

**Note:** If I simply remove Answer CMD from dialplan then billsec variable is showing the correct call time and this makes sense because channel was not answered and CDR(answer) will be assigned as soon as called party answers the channel. But the problem is that in my complete dialplan I have to answer the channel before making the call because I need to interact with user beforehand and it needs the channel to be answered.

BTW, I am using *Asterisk 13.0.0-beta1*. Could any of you guys let me know how can I achieve what I want to do please?

Comment: First tip i can give you - no use beta version of asterisk. Even asterisk 12 can be unpredictable and work not as described in doc.

Comment: @arheops, Thanks for your tip. However I am somehow stuck to Asterisk 13 because there is a feature added in this version that I really need it. Any other hint which might help me though?

Comment: @arheops, All I could do was to upgrade to beta2 but unfortunately the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

If basic CDR functionality is not enough for billing, check out CEL (Channel Event Logging). Supports all the DB backends, and has all the event's about a call (timestamped) that you possibly ever need.

Comment: That could be a workaround here. However, do you know a way of accessing these information within dialplan? I don't want to read an extra database for my billing system.

Answer (score 0):

ResetCDR() is your friend. I use this now so that I can track the original call duration and the portion of the call after it's transferred by the called party. This actually creates a second CDR record and should then contain the billsecs to match the conversation time.

Not 100% sure on all that but, give it a whirl, I think it's what you want.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ResetCDR

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already tried both ResetCDR and ForkCDR and I had no luck with them! Any other idea?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean my "I had no lick with them"? Did the CDR not fork or split into a second CDR which had the correction billsecs? Did the CDR not split at all? Were the seconds just wrong?

Comment: Well, I used ResetCDR and ForkCDR but still after using them CDR(duration) is equal to CDR(billsec). Worth to say that C option in Dial application is similar to ResetCDR.

Comment: You have try different options in Forkcdr. See asterisk -rx "core show application ForkCDR"

Comment: I would have to do some testing but, I am certain that ResetCDR or ForkCDR will solve your issue unless there is a bug in Asterisk 13?? I do this every day to determine the call time for the transferred portion of a call which we charge differently for. I do this on Asterisk 1.8 though.

Comment: Well, as far as the dialplan is really simple and there are no many options to change, I'm going to agree with you. I think this has to be a bug in Asterisk 13. I've tried every possible combination of using ForkCDR and ResetCDR. maybe I missed something, however I'm going to submit a bug report.

Comment: Well, I've submitted a bug report but support team believes it's not a bug. You can see their response from the following link: https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-24439?filter=-4

Comment: I guess I would need to dig in and do some testing. Also would need to look at how I am determining the transferred portion of my calls now. Unable to do that now, too much happening at the moment sorry. I will look at it as soon as I can to see if there is anything valuable I can add. One other method would be to use an AGI script to track start and end times of calls in a DB table or text file. If you do it in a text file, the call completion won't rely on the database being up which is good. You could then parse the text file every X minutes and move the log entries to a DB table.

Comment: I ended up using local channels to workaround the issue. Based on the reply that asterisk guys gave me seems that CDR module in asterisk is not supposed to do what I want and what we believe to be a bug or a must-have feature turns out to be their default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

might be too late to answer your question, but I have the exact same scenario.

What I did is, just before the call is forwarded to the C leg (A leg is caller, B leg is IVR who answers the call, C leg is destination where to forward the call), use ForkCDR(arve).

Something like:

```
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Incoming call from Provider X to User Y)
same => n,Macro(Execute_IVR)
same => n,ForkCDR(arve)
same => n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@userY)
```

And it works fine: I get 2 CDR rows, one for A leg to IVR with its own bill sec (say, 25 seconds), and the other one with call forwardinng A leg to C leg, also with its own billsec (say 350 seconds).
The sum of the 2 billsecs gives you the total duration of the call placed by A leg (caller).
The billsec of the second CDR gives you the conversation duration of that part of the call.